# Tensorflow: how to apply a function to the last dimension of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have an array. I want to create a mask based on the values in the last dimension of this array. In Numpy, I could do:

```
import numpy as np
room = np.array([
    [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
])
mask = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [1, 1, 1] if (x == [0, 0, 1]).all() else [0, 0, 0], axis=-1, arr=room)
result = mask * room
print(result)
```

In the above code, `room` is a (3, 3, 3) array based on which I created the mask. The mask created is also a (3, 3, 3) array and it will be used to multiply with other arrays to mask out unwanted elements.

But I have problem in achieving the same thing with Tensorflow. I have tried the following code,

```
room = tf.constant([
    [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]],
    [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
])
room = tf.reshape(room, shape=(9, -1))
mask = tf.map_fn(lambda x: [1, 1, 1] if x == [0, 0, 1] else [0, 0, 0], room)
```

but it ended with the following error:

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements. First structure: <dtype: 'int32'>, second structure: [0, 0, 0].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map_fn` has the parameter `dtype` that allows specifying the shape of the output if it's different from the shape of `x`.

However, this is not the problem.

You're mixing python conditions into a tensorflow operation: the python operations (like the if) are executed outside the graph while, instead, you want to define a graph that executes the desired op.

Let's dig into your problem:

1. You want to unroll the `room` variable along the first dimension: `map_fn` is OK for that.
2. You want to check if the current row (a vector of 3 elements) equals to `[0, 0, 1]`.

To do this you need to use a tensorflow condition, [`tf.cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/cond).

Note that `pred` must be a scalar. Thus, let's check using tensorflow operations only, if the current `row` equals to your desired row and reduce the result to a single scalar.

It this is true just return the constant value `[1,1,1]`, otherwise `[0,0,0]`.

```
mask = tf.map_fn(lambda row: tf.cond(
    tf.equal(
        tf.reduce_prod(tf.cast(tf.equal(row, tf.constant([0,0,1])), tf.int32)), 1),
    lambda: tf.constant([1,1,1]),
    lambda: tf.constant([0,0,0])), room)
```

Comment: dtype is used for specifying the data type, not the shape of data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As map_fn only works on tensors unpacked from the first dimension, I need to reshape my tensor to expose its last dimension in order for map_fn to work. Is there anyway to work around this.

Comment: As far as I know: no